# Why was this question not struck down as opinion based?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based

[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/89005/what-does-a-person-need-to-believe-about-jesus-in-order-to-be-saved-into-gods-f) asks what the minimum requirement is for a person to be saved. It doesn’t ask a specific denominations opinion on the topic.

How is this not opinion based? It seems rather obvious.

Comment: It's clearly scoped to Evangelicalism. Which may not be a denomination, but that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's remember the reason why the C.SE community wants to scope a question in the first place: **to enable an objective answer**.  After determining the topic (minimum requirement to be saved), check if the scope (evangelicalism) is unified enough to be able to answer it objectively, and **it does**.   Different answers merely reflect formulating different ways to express the same minimum requirement.

Notes:

1. Scope doesn't have to be a denomination, sometimes Protestantism is enough.  In other cases, we need to drill down to Reformed.
2. As Nigel said, by majority, community validated this scoping mechanism (established years ago), so no anarchy.
3. The community also needs to validate whether the scope provides the standard for *this* question, which is another 'yes' because evangelicalism STILL has currency of objectivity about this topic.  Maybe someday it will not, since a movement keeps evolving.  But given how being born again is *central* to evangelical self identity for the past 200+ years, it's safe to project that it will remain 'yes' in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Yea that’s a good point. +1 and I see now

Answer (score 1):

I edited it a bit, it was asking "Evangelical Christians" which often gets a little tricky to ascertain what an "Evangelical Christian Answer" constitutes.  I figure, lots of Bible, hopefully an actual quote from a commentator or at least a footnote from the Bible.

I've found that it's not really possible to project a Catholic view of Scripture onto every question, where a higher power does interpretation for you, just have to roll with it.  As long as the answer doesn't contradict the question.  Which I think only a predestination Calvinistic or a not-even-remotely Catholic works-trumps-faith strawman view of the Bible would constitute a Biblical worldview that didn't think there was a divine prescription for salvation.

So yeah, it gets pretty open ended.  Maybe the question should be closed as "too broad".

Comment: I say close it and let the author be more specific. We do it all the time and I don’t see why we should be giving it a pass.

Comment: @LukeHill The community has given it seven up-votes (10 up/3 down)which is quite a high figure on this site : and no close-votes. So the community appears to backing the question.

Comment: @NigelJ upvoting doesn’t determine the quality of a question. Rules are rules regardless of how much people like the question.

Comment: @LukeHill Community is community : no matter what the rules say. The sabbath was made for man : not man for the sabbath. The site was made to serve the interests of users : users were not made to satisfy the rules of the site. We, the users, have expressed the usefulness of the question.

Comment: @NigelJ this isn’t an anarchy. We still have rules that people need to abide by.

Comment: @LukeHill It is not anarchy. It is democracy. And the people have voted. If the  minority attempt to overturn the vote of the majority : then _that_ is anarchy.

Comment: @PeterTurner `I figure, lots of Bible` You inspired me to update [my answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89013/10672) with LOTS of Bible Verses (14 of them!).  But I don't just do cherry pick without coherence.  There are all contextually valid and I put them into an integrated evangelically understood perspective.